# general footnotes in xtable

Tags: r, sweave, xtable

I am using sweave to create pdf. Using xtable, I am trying to insert a general footnotes under the table (i.e: This symbol means bla bla bla). I've tried a lot of things and everything get me an error (or just do nothing).
Here's my code:

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
library(xtable)
resmat<-matrix(c("Income","inc1","inc2","inc3","inc4","inc5","inc6","inc7","inc8","inc9","inc10","OddsMale",paste(toString(l1[2]),"*"),paste(toString(l1[3]),"*"),paste(toString(l1[4]),"*"), l1[5],"base income",paste(toString(l1[6]),"^"),paste(toString(l1[7]),"*"),paste(toString(l1[8]),"*"),paste(toString(l1[9]),"*"),paste(toString(l1[10]),"*"),"OddsFemale",paste(toString(lf1[2]),"*"),paste(toString(lf1[3]),"*"),lf1[4], lf1[5],"base income",paste(toString(lf1[6]),"^"),paste(toString(lf1[7]),"^"),paste(toString(lf1[8]),"*"),paste(toString(lf1[9]),"*"),paste(toString(lf1[10]),"*")),11,3)


<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=

tab<-xtable(resmat,caption="Odds of Having Mental Health Given\\\\ Income per Gender, CCHS 2009-2012")
print(tab,include.rownames=FALSE,include.colnames=FALSE,hline.after = c(-1),caption.placement="top")

@
```

If anyone could help me! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! What does this have anything to do with `latex3`?